# Replaces all names found in a column that matches a name from a different column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that are laid out as follows:

**Table A**

```
|---------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      name           |     info                                                                                  |
|---------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|          1          |  Dark Magician is a normal monster. It can be used with cards such as Dark Magician Girl. |
|          2          |  Blue-Eyes White Dragon is a normal dragon monster. Dragon Capture Jar counters this card.|
|---------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

**Table B**

```
|--------------------- |
|      name            | 
|----------------------|
|Dark Magician         |
|Dark Magician Girl    |
|Blue-Eyes White Dragon|
|Dragon Capture Jar    |
|----------------------|
```

So I am comparing `tablea.info` to `tableb.name` and if it finds a match, I want to replace the matched name with `<a href="/name">name</a>`

My expected output would be as such for **Table A**:

```
|---------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      name           |     info                                                                                                                                                          |
|---------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|          1          |  <a href="/Dark Magician">Dark Magician</a> is a normal monster. It can be used with cards such as <a href="/Dark Magician Girl">Dark Magician Girl</a>.          |
|          2          |  <a href="/Blue-Eyes White Dragon">Blue-Eyes White Dragon</a> is a normal dragon monster. <a href="/Dragon Capture Jar">Dragon Capture Jar</a> counters this card.|
|---------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I'm not sure what the most optimal route of doing this would be.

I think I compare `tableb.name` with `tableb.info` but I'm struggling with the update part.
I'm thinking I do a replace? So Something like:

`REPLACE(ta.info,'%Dark Magician%','%<a href="/Dark Magician">Dark Magician</a>%')`

Advice on the best way of going about this would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit the question to add the complete query that you are trying (which is failing). Also, what is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: "Dark Magician Girl" contains "Dark Magician" which makes things trick(y/ier).

Comment: *""Dark Magician Girl" contains "Dark Magician" which makes things trick(y/ier). "* @Strawberry maybe a little bit, the topicstarter could  trying ordering on the string lenght DESC in a delivered table (subquery) before updating, that seams like a "valid" workaround for this data example when some parts are duplicated..